# Handle variable string arrays inside a struct (C)

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have to know if there is a way to declare inside a struct a variable length string array, something like that

```
struct node {
               int k;
               char * arr[length_variable];
            }
```

Now I'm doing something like that

```
 struct node {
                  int k;
                  char ** arr;
                 }

int main()
{
  ...
  struct node * n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  n->arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*length_of_first_array); //the length of the array is variable
  n->arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*length_first_string+1); //+1 is for \0 character
  strcpy(n->arr[0],"word");
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately analising the output code using valgrind tool 'memory check' it seems that something is wrong with my mallocs.

Comment: "something is wrong with my mallocs" - well, the code you posted here doesn't free any of the allocated memory, so that might be the problem

Comment: What’s “something”? Please show the valgrind output.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna post it

Comment: 10,100,010 (80,000 direct, 10,020,010 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
Error is detected at the line 'n->arr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*length_of_first_array); '

Comment: (Valgrind's output has very big numbers because I'm doing some massive tests on my code)

Comment: Valgrind appears to be recognizing that your malloc is allocating memory that is never released within the scope in which it's defined.

Comment: If you use a VLA of pointers in your struct -- how will the compiler ever be able to determine the size for that struct type at compile time? Makes pointer arithmetic impossible -- you can't have a variable sized object as a member of a struct save and except for a Flexible Array Member as it's last member [C11 Standard - 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3). A `VLA != FAM`

Comment: And this is the reason you use c++ instead of c.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` etc., for reasons detailed elsewhere ad nauseam. And in C, `sizeof(char)` has always been defined as exactly 1.

Answer (score 2):

A VLA may not be a member of a struct or union type:

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
> ...
> 9 A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a
> variably modified type.<sup>123)</sup>...
>
> ---
>
> <sup>123) A structure or union cannot contain a member with a variably modified type because member names
> are not ordinary identifiers as defined in 6.2.3.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

The code you've posted is correct as far as allocation is concerned - are you properly deallocating that memory when you're done with it?  You have to make sure you `free` each `n->arr[i]` *before* you `free` `n->arr`, and you have to `free` `n->arr` before `free`ing `n`.